# Delphi TNetEncoding.Base64 works but data are cutted

Tags: string, encoding, base64, delphi-xe, delphi-10.3-rio

I have this code, in which I want to convert a file to Base64 format using `TNetEncoding.Base64`. It works, but it cuts my data to a few lines. My question is why? Delphi's `String` can contains approx 2<sup>30</sup> characters, or 2GB of data, so why does this not work properly?

I want to use this conversion for PDF files approx 3-6MB and store these strings into an SQL database (this isn't shown in the code example).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  inp: String;
  s: string;
begin
  try
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
      if FileExists(OpenDialog1.FileName) then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
        s := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(Memo1.Lines.Text);
      end;

    memo1.Lines.Text := s;
  except
    ShowMessage('error');
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, rather than using `FileExists()` after `TOpenDialog.Execute()` return `True`, you should instead enable `TOpenDialog`'s `ofPathMustExist` and `ofFileMustExist` options, then `Execute()` can't exit as `True` if the user enters a non-existent file.

That being said, a `.PDF` file is binary data, you can't load it into a `TMemo`, which works only with textual data.

Instead, load the file into a `TFileStream` or `TMemorySteam`, and then pass that to the `TStream` overload of `Base64.Encode()`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Input: TFileStream;
  //Input: TMemoryStream;
  Output: TStringStream;
begin
  try
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      Input := TFileStream.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName, fmOpenRead or fShareDenyWrite);
      // Input := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        //Input.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
        Output := TStringStream.Create;
        try
          TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(Input, Output);
          Memo1.Lines.Text := Output.DataString;
        finally
          Output.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Input.Free;
      end;
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage('error');
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, use `TMemoryStream` or `TFile.ReadAllBytes()` with `Base64.EncodeBytesToString()`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Input: TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      Input := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        Input.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
        Memo1.Lines.Text := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(Input.Memory, Input.Size);
      finally
        Input.Free;
      end;
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage('error');
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
      Memo1.Lines.Text := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(TFile.ReadAllBytes(OpenDialog1.FileName));
  except
    ShowMessage('error');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Last example not workyng show empty lines in memo

 Memo1.Lines.Text := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(TFile.ReadAllBytes(OpenDialog1.FileName));

Comment: @milenjao did you verify that `ReadAllBytes()` is not returning an empty byte array?